# mongoose: TypeError: [function name] is not a function. when trying to create mongoose instanse

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a web application with MEAN stack, and I'm getting a headache with mongoose instance.

Here are (piece of) my codes:

**my route**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var accDocService = require('../services/accdoc-services');

router.post('/dailybook', function(req, res) {
   accDocService.addAccDoc(req.body, function(error) {
      if (error) throw error;
   });
});
```

**accdoc-service.js**

```
var accDoc = require('../models/accdoc').accDoc;

console.log(typeof accDoc);

exports.addAccDoc = function(accDoc, next) {
   var newAccDoc = new accDoc({
      number: '45645'
   });

   newAccDoc.save(function(error) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log("doc created");
   });
};
```

**accdoc.js (the model file)**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var accDocSchema = new Schema({
   number: String
});

var accDoc = mongoose.model('accDoc', accDocSchema);

module.exports = {
   accDoc: accDoc
};
```

After sending the post request, I'm getting `TypeError: accDoc is not a function`

Also, `console.log(typeof accDoc);` in second file, returns *function*.

### EDIT 1

In **accdoc-services**, if I move `var AccDoc = require('../models/accdoc');` to the `addAccDoc` function, everything works fine.

Am I missing some node.js stuff here? I'm watching a tutorial video from Lynda that there is not some *scope* problem like this.
[here is an image from Lynda tutorial](http://pasteboard.co/2eujSsa5.png)

Comment: `exports.addAccDoc = function(accDoc, next) {` i don't understand why this function is accepting an `accDoc` param. it makes the `require` at the top of that file irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if I don't pass `accDoc`, how can I use `new accDoc({`?

Comment: Directly. You defined it at the top, you can access that inside the function if you weren't overriding it with that parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the new keyword for creating a model instance of accDoc

```
var accDoc = require('../models/accdoc').accDoc;

console.log(typeof accDoc);

exports.addAccDoc = function(accDoc, next) {
   var newAccDoc = new accDoc({ // HERE new was missing!
      number: '45645'
   });

   newAccDoc.save(function(error) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log("doc created");
   });
};
```

Comment: No difference. I was using `new` keyword before, but I saw [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications) and I thought maybe without `new`?
But same error in both.

Comment: Try module.exports = accDoc; instead of your module.exports = {accDoc: accDoc}; And leave keyword new as suggested ;-) Otherwise, there could be a possibility where you have a caching problem. Btw. is the error on the line I mentioned?

Comment: No luck. and yes, the error is from that line.
I think i'm going to test it on some online IDE.

Comment: you could try c9.io, it comes with free space and mean stack is possible ;-) If it doesn't work I could try to reproduce it later that afternoon.

Comment: adding `new` before a function call that is throwing the error *undefined is not a function* won't magically make the function defined.

Comment: I was blind, but now I see ;-)

Your write var accDoc = require('../models/accdoc').accDoc;

and a few lines down your function header exports.addAccDoc = function(accDoc, next) ....

The problem is, that both the field and the parameter have the same name, which cannot work.